# Potential Imagemagick linear-gradient bug?

Tags: imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I am trying to build a rectangle with a gradient in Imagemagick. When I run my script with a solid color fill I get the expected behavior for building rectangles, but when I use a gradient for the -fill I get an odd behavior for the gradients where they appear to restart in the middle of the  shape they are being drawn into. Can anyone recommend a fix or work around for this? In the example below I only apply the gradient to the bottom spread as an example (look at the black, black/white comparisons). In the first image it is filled black as expected, but in the second image the gradient 'misbehaves' and restarts in the middle of the spread for no apparent reason.

Thanks.

Example of working command with result:

```
convert -size 240x702 -fill black -draw "rectangle 40,2500 280,1798"  legend.png legend.png
```

[image]

Example of broken command with result:

```
convert -size 240x702 -fill gradient:'#FFFFFF'-'#000000' -draw "rectangle 40,2500 280,1798"  legend.png legend.png
```

[image]

Comment: If you don't get a response in a day then maybe open a bug at  https://github.com/ImageMagick/ImageMagick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but your ImageMagick command line syntax is in error in several ways:

> convert -size 240x702 -fill gradient:'#FFFFFF'-'#000000' -draw
>   "rectangle 40,2500 280,1798"  legend.png legend.png

```
First, you have your input legend.png image after your draw, so there is nothing to draw on. You need to read your input right after convert. See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#syntax

Second do not put quotes about each color in the gradient. Just put it around both.

Third, your -size argument is smaller than the size of the rectangle (and in fact is not used for anything). So you are trying to draw with a larger area than the image you are drawing on.

Fourth, there is no -fill for a gradient in Magick Vector Graphics as listed at https://imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php

Fifth, your command has no color involved in the gradient, but you show a gradated color image. Where is the color coming from or where is the grayscale gradient being used?
```

I do not have your input legend.png image. But what you want to do is create a gradient image and then composite that over your legend background at the correct location. Since I do not have your legend, I will use your output for the legend.

```
convert legend.png \( -size 240x2340 gradient:'#FFFFFF-#000000' \) -geometry +40+160 -compose over -composite result.png
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your input and suggestions. Your answer has really helped and given me everything I need to complete this and implement a better solution.